# What do I place here (Lorem Ipsum)?

Tags: php, basic-authentication

```
`<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "groboch123"); ?>

<?php
$Realm = "<big><span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'/>Worked!</span></big>";?>

<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))/*Need to be !isset*/{
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
echo 'Lorem Ipsum'; /* Make the user see this */
exit;
} else {
echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>`
```

I am trying to create an authorized login.

I'm looking for ways here to improve my code. I want the Lorem Ipsum to be the Realm. :) Hopefully, this can get done someway.

This will be a great video game for computers. I am trying to add this prompt. Or, alternatively, if this is an too expensive method maybe using the prompt() to validate credentials??

Comment: *"I want the Lorem Ipsum to be the Realm"* What stops you from doing so?

Comment: @Olivier I want to place an entire document within the '' aswheareas the Lorem Ipsum is placed. But don't know how to do this.

Comment: You can't when using Basic auth. The user will only see the name defined in `realm="..."`.

Comment: Or perhaps using this <?php if ($loggedin:?> whereas I correct the :

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out the answer myself. Using {}, in the way it's possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).